# BeautifulSoup does not work for some web sites

Tags: python, web-crawler, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this sript:

```
import urrlib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.shoptop.ru/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
divs = soup.findAll('a')
print divs
```

For [this](http://www.shoptop.ru) web site, it prints empty list? What can be problem? I am running on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: BeautifulSoup works only for static pages. If its full of JavaScript/ AJAX, you need to first run those scripts, get the HTML code and `read`

Comment: I ran the code and it showed me a big list of `<a>`

Comment: In my case the problem is not with Javascript/Ajax, because it works on other machines, I mean on my local machine(Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit), but it does not work on my server Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Comment: @Surya it work in some machines, I think there are some packages which bs4 is dependent on, especially for unicode characters, but I do not know which

Comment: well, then try this : add `BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")`. Tell me whether its working or not?

Comment: actually I had some problem with BeautifulSoup when I was using apache. So, just try a couple of parser libraries mentioned in the documentation http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @Surya you have also typo ;) (html.parser), but it works, can you add answer to this question with explanation, so I can mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are quite couple of bugs in BeautifulSoup which might raise some unknown errors. I had a similar issue when working on apache using `lxml` parser

So, just try to use other couple of parsers mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
```

This should work!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How did you know this? Why does this happen? Why does it happen on some servers but not others?

Comment: @frabcus I dont remember how - I faced this error in `mod_wsgi`, `apache`, `django` environment.. I guess, it was caused by some cpython implementations (since lxml, mod_wsgi are largely in C).. so, I tried with html.parser and it worked!! don't really know the exact reason.. (probably this reason might not be right too)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you have a few mistakes in your code urrlib2 should be urllib2, I've fixed the code for you and this works using BeautifulSoup 3

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.shoptop.ru/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
divs = soup.findAll('a')
print divs
```

Comment: `urrlib2` was just a typo. there isn't any module as such on that name.

Comment: Thanks @Surya, I caught that.