# BeautifulSoap does not work on subsequent pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I cannot get the title of subsequent pages. Where is the problem?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

# First page
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://yeniemlak.az/elan/axtar?emlak=1&elan_nov=1&seher=0&metro=0&qiymet=&qiymet2=&mertebe=&mertebe2=&otaq=&otaq2=&sahe_m=&sahe_m2=&sahe_s=&sahe_s2=').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup.title) # shows title as expected

# Second page
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://yeniemlak.az/elan/axtar?emlak=1&elan_nov=1&seher=0&metro=0&qiymet=&qiymet2=&mertebe=&mertebe2=&otaq=&otaq2=&sahe_m=&sahe_m2=&sahe_s=&sahe_s2=&page=2').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup.title) # shows None
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure why only your second case is failing. As mentioned in some other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650700/beautifulsoup-does-not-work-for-some-web-sites), sometimes using other parsers might work.

I could get the second page to work fine with `html.parser`. Though it threw a warning about decoding errors.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

# Second page
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://yeniemlak.az/elan/axtar?emlak=1&elan_nov=1&seher=0&metro=0&qiymet=&qiymet2=&mertebe=&mertebe2=&otaq=&otaq2=&sahe_m=&sahe_m2=&sahe_s=&sahe_s2=&page=2').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
print(soup.title) # Now works
```

Output

```
Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<title>YENIEMLAK.AZ Satılır Bina ev menzil  </title>
```

Comment: This works, it also works if you switch to use Requests instead of urllib.